# java. lang. ClassNotFoundException : mvn package

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, maven-plugin

Trying to build my spark-scala maven project project, when I'm doing

1. mvn compile
2. mvn package
3. spark-submit --master local --class Main  C:\workspace\Example\target\abc.jar

error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main class

Can someone help me on this?

My pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
<artifactId>sample</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-network-shuffle_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-network-yarn_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.123</finalName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <finalName>abc</finalName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: You need to provide the jar path to `spark-submit`

Comment: @zsxwing I provided the path , but facing the same issue.

Comment: I don't see it. Could you provide the exact command you used?

Comment: spark-submit --master local --class Main C:\workspace\Example\target\abc.jar
This is command I gave

Comment: I think mvn compile is not creating class files in target folder, how to reslove this issue.

Comment: `class files` or `jar`? `mvn compile` generates `class files`, while `mvn package` generates `jar`. By the way, did you forget the package name, or you just created a class called Main without any package name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137610/discussion-between-vikv-and-zsxwing).